# I want to give border Color to Linear percent indicator in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I've tried to give border to linear progress indication by using container but it is not working for me..
Here is the Code.

```
Container(
  width: Get.width*0.8,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.black
    ),
  ),
  child: LinearPercentIndicator(
    // width: Get.width*0.8,
    lineHeight:Get.height*0.04,
    percent: percent/100,
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
    progressColor: AppColors.orangeTextColor,
    center: Text(
      percent.toString() + "%",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 12.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        color: Colors.black
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`LinearPercentIndicator` comes with a default padding of `EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0)`. Changing it to zero like this will fix it:

```
LinearPercentIndicator(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
```